# In elgg chinese language not loading?

Tags: elgg

I am use elgg 1.8. in that i use `zh` means Chinese language. in one page i need a page without header and footer so i just make a page handler and echo content with `elgg_echo` function. it work with the `en` (English) language but when i change to `zh` it's display a garbage values.

I am also use this trick for that

```
echo elgg_echo('user:chinese_zodiac','zh');
```

but it works on `en` language but not for `zh`. this function also display same garbage value like this `ç”Ÿè‚–` but i want text like `生肖`.

Comment: Does the translation to Chinese work fine in other places? Also make sure that you have mbstring php extension enabled.

Comment: Yes Chinese work great in other page but they all have header and footer included. and i have this one page without header and footer. and yes mbstring extension is enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, guys trying to help me. but finally i got the trick.

I am use this function or trick to handle this problem...

```
reload_all_translations();
```

This function reload all translations from all registered paths.
This is only called by functions which need to know all possible translations.